# Подскажите jquery/angularjs пагинацию

Tags: jquery, pagination

Добрый день.

Прогуглил много пагинаций, но так и не смог подключить, чтоб нормально работала.

В общем, есть информация в <div>. И нужно разделить по страницам, например, по 10 или 50 и т.д. Ну и чтоб не перезагружать страницу при этом.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, готовый код с примером.
Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Есть jplist.core, правда довольно тяжеловат(~49кБ)
[DEMO](https://jplist.com/layoutexamples/cars)

Comment: Вы уверены, что стоит использовать экскаватор, чтобы посадить картошку? :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, а Вы уверены, что человек сажает картошку, а не строит дом ;)

Comment: @flax, если человек спрашивает о посадке картошки, то это не значит, что он строит дом. Можно, конечно, впарить ему экскаватор вместо лопаты, но, боюсь, что урожай картошки он не соберёт

Comment: @MasterAlex, упоминаний о картошке не увидел, оттуда и экскаватор. С чего Вы взяли, что я что-то впариваю, я предлагаю решение. Знаете решение лучше?

Comment: @flax, картошка это пагинация, дом - куча ненужного функционала по вашей ссылке, вот например есть [лёгкий модуль на 4 кб][1] и [demo к нему][2]

[1]: https://github.com/begriffs/angular-paginate-anything
[2]: http://begriffs.com/angular-paginate-anything/?page=0&perPage=5

Comment: @MasterAlex, так оформили бы сразу ответом, хороший модуль. Во всяком случае полезнее холивара.